# What is MongoDB's fsync for?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've been using MongoDB for some time, and saw that `fsync` waits for data to be flushed to disk. Ok, so i thought it was the solution for safety of the data.

It worked well by takes long, longer than SQL alternative. Then I saw that I can put the `syncdelay` to `0`, then speed came back, but I thought how it would be in the future with many many concurrent requests. So I removed `fsync` option from the updates and inserts and removed the `syncdelay` configuration option.

To test if the data was being written I quickly checked Rockmongo after I made an update and the data was actually there, super fast!

So really, what is `fsync` for if it makes the writes slow and without it the writes happen, and fast anyway?

Answer (score 5):

Per Mongo documentation:

> The primary use of `fsync` is to flush and lock the database for backups.

also

> The `fsync` operation blocks all other write operations while its running.

The blocking appears to be the reason.

Comment: The fsync operation blocks all other write operations for a while it runs. -there seems to be a typo "operations for a while it runs"

Answer (score 4):

`fsync` is technically an admin command that forces a flush of all data to disk. You shouldn't have to use it in your code, not normally at least. It's used to lock the database for backups and so on.

Data safety in MongoDB comes from replication/sharding/journaling, not from forcing writes. That kind of defeats the purpose of the thing.

The Java driver wraps this 'write-and-sync' concept in the `WriteConcern` class, which I've never really liked much. You shouldn't have to decide which part of your data is more or less important, but rather just trust the tool to do its job.

Also, if you set `syncdelay` to zero make sure you turn journaling off. See [this](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/--syncdelay).

Comment: My biggest concern was that Mongo stored data on memory then to disk after the syncdelay, and if the user receives a sucess msg but the hardware failed before that sync, basically, a big fail. 

Am i right? or is there a solution to this?

Comment: Again, replication. MongoDB is a distributed data store, not an RDBMS. A single instance of MongoDB is essentially _useless_, because you can't rely on it being durable on its own. Once you have two instances then you don't need to worry about hardware failing.

Comment: A single instance with journaling is fine for durability, particularly with the Journaling write concern.

Comment: @MrKurt no, it's not. When "hardware failed" which is Hadrian's concern in this case. Journaling is not going to save you from a corrupted partition or a failed HDD, it just ensures that the database is in a consistent state when there is an unexpected termination of the mongod process instance. Replication on the other hand, ensures you have a sync'ed copy of your data in a separate hardware enclosure.

Comment: That's a different definition of "durable" that people normally use for DBs. Durable means the DB is in a consistant state even when something dies mid-write. With the journaling write concern, data is "safe" as soon as the command returns.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have said, the `fsync` command forces a flush and is normally used right before you lock data files for a point in time snapshot.

There is an "fsync" [write concern option](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getLastError+Command#getLastErrorCommand-%7B%7Bfsync%7D%7D) on `getLastError` that will wait to return into all pending data has been flushed to disk. You normally wouldn't use this though, the "j" option (which returns as soon as journaling has happened) is much faster to return and still ensures durable writes. You can pass either through an update/insert command as the safe option in your driver of choice to let it automatically run the `getLastError` command for you.